# Accessing parentNode with button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the parentNode of a button element (div) but I get an error every time. Here is what I am trying to do. Simply put, this is a page that had 2 divs on it. I only want one div displayed at a time. There is a button on the first page that switches to the second and a button on the second that is supposed to return to the first (but doesn't because it can't locate the parentNode).

```
        <div class="pageContent" id="page_3">
            <div class="primaryPage" id="primaryPage_3">
                <h2>Bills_______________________</h2>
                <p>Here are my monthly Bills<br><br>blah blah</p>
                <button type="button" id="billButton" onclick="newBill()">Add Bill</button>
            </div>
            <div class="pageContent" id="billPage">
                <p>this is the bill page</p>
                <button class="backButton" onclick="back()">Back</button>
            </div>
        </div>

function newBill(){
document.getElementById("primaryPage_3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("billPage").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("billPage").setAttribute("back", "primaryPage_3");
}

function back(){
var previousPage = this.parentNode.getAttribute("back");
this.parentNode.style.display = "none";    
document.getElementById(previousPage).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this...

```
onclick="back()"
```

to this...

```
onclick="back.call(this)"
```

---

Invoking a function using `.call()` lets you manually set the calling context *(the `this` value)* of the function being invoked. Here it's setting it to the current element.